# Camera rotates around itself while following nurbs path

Tags: animation, camera

I am trying to do an animation around an object where my camera is following a nurbs path. I have added to modifiers to my camera; follow path(nurbs path) and dampened track(object). But when I modify the cameras offset factor to move the camera, the camera also rotates around the dampened track axis as it moves along the path. [image]

link to blend file https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtTOS_R1m1K5g-MUoz4fRruUcuZexg?e=FUvj0C

Comment: Hello coule you please share your file? replace the target object with an empty for example

Comment: added link to file

Comment: yes it looks like you need to create some rotation keyframes on its Y axis

Comment: Excellent, that solved it! Thank you!

Comment: I meant on its Z axis of couse, not Y  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can't avoid these rotations, to fix it, rotate your camera and create some keyframes on its own Z axis.